# Animated counter not animating at all - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following JavaScript animation:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // should return a number like 100
    var total = parseInt(document.getElementById('foo').className);
    function showBars(bars) {
        document.getElementById("bar").innerHTML = bars + " bars";
        if (bars < total) {
            setTimeout(showBars(bars + 1), 20);
        }
    }
    console.log(total);
    if (total > 0) showBars(0);
}
```

HTML:

```
<span id="foo" class="100" />
<p id='bar' class='100'>100 Bars</p>
```

So, instead of having the desired effect of incrementing the bars one by one (visible to the user), I just see the number posted (`100`). I know the problem is on the `window.onload` but how could I replace the `window.onload` by other event that will produce the result I'm looking for?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `bars` is defined as a function argument. And in HTML, [classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes) can begin with a digit (even if that is not a CSS identifier).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No, `parseInt` is fine ... I just saw the correct number in a `alert(total)`

Comment: @philippe: It may work on this browser or that. But relying on things that are invalid is just asking for trouble. I suggest a `data-*` attribute instead.

Comment: I don't think you're using `setTimeout` correctly.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the advice. Will modify the `HTML` to add `data-index-number` as you suggested.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Please see the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#classes): "*There are no additional restrictions on the tokens authors can use in the `class` attribute*". And the [validator](http://validator.w3.org) accepts `<!doctype html><title>Title</title><a class="0"></a>` ;-)

Comment: @Oriol: Ah, okay, so it's valid in HTML, and invalid in CSS. Fair 'nuff, there's always been a mismatch there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the primary problem is here:

```
setTimeout(showBars(bars + 1), 20);
```

That code **calls** the `showBars` function and then passes its return value into `setTimeout`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

If you replace it with

```
setTimeout(showBars.bind(null, bars + 1), 20);
```

...it will pass a function to `setTimeout` that, when called, will call `showBars` with `bars + 1` as the argument.

**Live Example:** *(I also removed both `class` attributes with classes starting with digits, replacing the one on `foo` with `data-max` as discussed in comments)*

```js
window.onload = function() {
    // should return a number like 100
    var total = parseInt(document.getElementById('foo').getAttribute("data-max"));
    function showBars(bars) {
        document.getElementById("bar").innerHTML = bars + " bars";
        if (bars < total) {
            setTimeout(showBars.bind(null, bars + 1), 20);
        }
    }
    if (total > 0) showBars(0);
};
```

```html
<span id="foo" data-max="180" />
<p id='bar'>100 Bars</p>
```

Comment: Or you could wrap the function call in a function: ` function(){ showBars(bars+1); }`

Comment: @Jakar: Indeed you could, in this case, as `bars` won't change before it's run.